# Display and fill multiple layer_text layers in ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I am having trouble using the "fill" property for more than one text layer:

```
Month = seq(1,12)
Median_Peak_Duration = c(6,5,4,3,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5.5)
PeakyMonth = ifelse(Median_Peak_Duration > 3, 'Non-Peaky', 'Peaky')
testDat = data.frame(Month, Median_Peak_Duration,PeakyMonth)

testDat %>%
ggvis(x = ~Month, y = ~Median_Peak_Duration, fill = ~PeakyMonth) %>%
layer_bars(width = .8) %>%
# Annotation
layer_lines(x = ~Month, y = 3, strokeDash := 6, strokeWidth := 3) %>%
layer_text(x = 6, y = 4.5, text:= "Some more Text", 
  fontSize := 12, align := "center", baseline := "top", fill := "black") %>%
layer_text(x = 6, y = 3, text:= "Some Text", 
  fontSize := 12, align := "center", baseline := "top", fill := "black")
```

This causes no text to display while this works:

```
testDat %>%
ggvis(x = ~Month, y = ~Median_Peak_Duration, fill = ~PeakyMonth) %>%
layer_bars(width = .8) %>%
# Annotation
layer_lines(x = ~Month, y = 3, strokeDash := 6, strokeWidth := 3) %>%
layer_text(x = 6, y = 4.5, text:= "Some more Text", 
  fontSize := 12, align := "center", baseline := "top", fill := "black")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid needing `fill` in `layer_text` to control the color of the text you could move it to be inside `layer_bars`.

I think you are also going to want to put the text you are plotting into a `data.frame, otherwise it looks like the text gets plotted many times and looks funny (this would be like what happens with`ggplot2:geom_text`).

One option:

```
testDat %>%
    ggvis(x = ~Month, y = ~Median_Peak_Duration) %>%
    layer_bars(width = .8, fill = ~PeakyMonth) %>%
    # Annotation
    layer_lines(x = ~Month, y = 3, strokeDash := 6, strokeWidth := 3) %>%
    layer_text(data = data.frame(x = 6, y = 4.5, text = "Some more text"), 
             x = ~x, y = ~y, text := ~text,
             fontSize := 12, align := "center", baseline := "top") %>%
    layer_text(data = data.frame(x = 6, y = 3, text = "Some Text"),
             x = ~x, y = ~y, text := ~text,
             fontSize := 12, align := "center", baseline := "top")
```

If leaving `fill` in overall `ggvis`:

```
testDat %>%
    ggvis(x = ~Month, y = ~Median_Peak_Duration, fill = ~PeakyMonth) %>%
    layer_bars(width = .8) %>%
    # Annotation
    layer_lines(x = ~Month, y = 3, strokeDash := 6, strokeWidth := 3) %>%
    layer_text(data = data.frame(x = 6, y = 4.5, text = "Some more text"), 
             x = ~x, y = ~y, text := ~text,
             fontSize := 12, align := "center", baseline := "top", fill := "black") %>%
    layer_text(data = data.frame(x = 6, y = 3, text = "Some Text"),
             x = ~x, y = ~y, text := ~text,
             fontSize := 12, align := "center", baseline := "top", fill := "black")
```

[image]

Comment: so in your first solution, the key is moving `fill` from the `ggvis()` parentheses into the `layer_bars()` parentheses, so it doesn't interfere with the `layer_text()`, which i kind of understand. 

What is the key to your second solution? putting text-data in the `data.frame()`, or adding the `var := ~var` bits? Or both?

Comment: @RyanStochastic Putting things in a data.frame in both solutions gets rid of the problem with overplotting of the text, which you likely saw when changing `fill` to `stroke`.  When the `fill` is set globally, though, the plot expects a `fill` variable in this data.frame and will error if it doesn't find it.  So you have to set it to something so I used `"black"`(oddly, the `fill` color will affect the color of the text).

Answer (score 0):

try `stroke` instead of `fill`?

```
testDat %>%
    ggvis(x = ~Month, y = ~Median_Peak_Duration, fill = ~PeakyMonth) %>%
    layer_bars(width = .8) %>%
    # Annotation
    layer_lines(x = ~Month, y = 3, strokeDash := 6, strokeWidth := 3) %>%
    layer_text(x = 6, y = 4.5, text:= "Some more Text", 
               fontSize := 12, align := "center", baseline := "top", stroke := "black") %>%
    layer_text(x = 6, y = 3, text:= "Some Text", 
               fontSize := 12, align := "center", baseline := "top", stroke := "black")
```